# Fetching 2 different results from one stored procedure with PDO/PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

Building a Symfony 4 API with SQL Server database, I'm confronted to a problem: I have to fetch two different results from one stored procedure.

The first result is an array of datas, and the second is just an int value.

I'm coding a back-end pagination and this is why I need to get the datas, but also the total of rows I have in the table.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SP IDENTIFIER] 

    (
        @Limit INT,
        @Offset INT

    )
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL'
    FROM DataBaseName

SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM DataBaseName
ORDER BY Field1 DESC
OFFSET @Offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT @Limit ROW ONLY


END
```

When I'm testing my API, it's returning only the result of my first request (The rows number value).

Here is how my Repository method:

```
  public function getDatas($limit, $offset)
  {
    $request = "EXEC SPName ?, ?";
    $answer = $this->_em->getConnection()->prepare($request);
    $answer->bindParam(1, $limit);
    $answer->bindParam(2, $offset);
    $answer->execute(); 


    return $answer->fetchAll();
  }
```

Do you know any way to make PDO returning all the results he's getting from the request? Maybe in a fetch option, or by somehow doing a fetchAll loop in $answer?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.

You have to use the  the nextRowSet() method. You can call it on your statement object with Doctrine, but not anymore with Doctrine 2.
So, you first have to get the true PDO Object, by calling getWrappedConnection() method after getConnection().

After this, you just will have to loop in the datas and stack them into an array or object.

Here is my solution:

```
  public function getPaginedSubscriptions($limit, $offset)
  {
    $sql = "EXEC DB_EXTRANET_V2.dbo.P_S_ORDER_00 ?, ?";
    $request = $this->_em->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $request->bindParam(1, $limit);
    $request->bindParam(2, $offset);
    $request->execute();

    do{
      $datas[] = $request->fetchAll();
    } while($request->nextRowSet());

    return $datas;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL Server supports stored procedures that can return more than one result set. With PHP and PDO you can retrieve these result sets with [PDOStatement::nextRowset()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) method. It is important to know, that even if you have output parameters in your stored procedure, you need to fetch all result sets to get output values.

You may try with this:

```
public function getDatas($limit, $offset)
{
    $request = "EXEC SPName ?, ?";
    $answer = $this->_em->getConnection()->prepare($request);
    $answer->bindParam(1, $limit);
    $answer->bindParam(2, $offset);
    $answer->execute(); 

    do {
        // Fetch records with $answer->fetchAll();
    while ($answer->nextRowset());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found it interesting! 

I don't get why, but this isn't working yet, it's like Doctrine doesn't know the nextRowset() method.

"Attempted to call an undefined method named "nextRowset" of class "Doctrine\DBAL\Statement"."

$answer doesn't seems to be a true PDO instance... !

Answer (score 1):

You've got to specify OUTPUT parameters for the stored procedure and your client code has to be able to accept the output.

It has been a few months since I have worked with SQL Server, but am quite sure the version I worked with did not allow ALTER for stored procedures and I don't have SQL Server any longer so I cannot test what I am handing off to you.

Also, I think you "think" the procedure is working the first time, but I guessing the variable is already loaded with a valid value therefore it appears to be getting set properly.

Please try the below and modify your client code to accept @myCount:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SP IDENTIFIER', 'P') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP PROCEDURE [SP IDENTIFIER];  
GO  

CREATE PROCEDURE [SP IDENTIFIER]
          @Limit INT, @Offset INT, @myCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON; 

SELECT @myCount = COUNT(*)
FROM DataBaseName

SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM DataBaseName
ORDER BY Field1 DESC
OFFSET @Offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT @Limit ROW ONLY

END
```